# Error while building FastCGI in a server running ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cgi, fastcgi

I want to interface FCGI with my C++ code in a server that runs ubuntu. I didn't find ubuntu under the list of tested platforms in the FCGI website, but I tried building it anyway.

`./configure` seems to work okay. But, when I run `make`, I get 2 errors, as pasted below:

`fcgio.cpp: In destructor 'virtual fcgi_streambuf::~fcgi_streambuf()':

    fcgio.cpp:50: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope

    fcgio.cpp: In member function 'virtual int fcgi_streambuf::overflow(int)':

    fcgio.cpp:70: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope

    fcgio.cpp:75: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope

    fcgio.cpp: In member function 'virtual int fcgi_streambuf::sync()':

    fcgio.cpp:86: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope

    fcgio.cpp:87: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope

    fcgio.cpp: In member function 'virtual int fcgi_streambuf::underflow()':

    fcgio.cpp:113: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope

    make[2]: *** [fcgio.lo] Error 1

    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/giridhar/fcgi-2.4.1-SNAP-0910052249/libfcgi'

    make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/giridhar/fcgi-2.4.1-SNAP-0910052249'

    make: *** [all] Error 2`

Help in fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed that EOF is a C macro and it requires `stdio.h` which wasn't included in the fcgio.cpp file.

Adding a `#include <stdio.h>` to the fcgio.cpp file solves the problem, and now FCGI builds fine on Ubuntu.